# What is actually 1.73 GHz, 555MHz, FSB

Tags: cpu, speed

I am owning a Acer Aspire laptop and its configuration are as follows:

- Intel Celeron M processor 430 (1.73 GHz, 533MHz FSB, 1MB L2 Cache
- Mobile Intel 940 GML Express chipset
- "14.1" WXGA wide TFT, LCD

and some more details. I would like to know what exactly is 1.73GHz, 533MHz, FSB? I know that it's something related to Processor speed, but i would like to have an formal idea of what actually this is, and how the laptop may work if the configuration were >2000GHz.

Another question would be:

- I use a Fedora 13 OS and it shows me the speed 16.2 MB/sec (approx.) when i transfer a movie or a file into an USB. Does, this transfer speed have any connection with the above configuration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first value, 1.73GHz, is the speed of the processor core, by other words, it is the speed that the instructions are processed.

The second value is the FSB, that means Front Side Bus, it is the speed of the bus that the processor uses to communicate with rest of the computer.

The speed of data transfer is limited by the write speed of the USB device. It is almost independent of CPU speed.